# How can i move my popup around?

Tags: jquery, css

I've tried using some css styling like so... `position: relative; right: 20px;`

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/supplement/j77eB/

So when someone hovers over the tooltips link i want the prop to be moved over to the right in stead of the bottom.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip({
        position: { my: "left+15 center", at: "right center"}
        content: function () {
            return $(this).prop('title');
        },
        show: null, 
        close: function (event, ui) {
            ui.tooltip.hover(

            function () {
                $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(400, 1);
            },

            function () {
                $(this).fadeOut("400", function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                })
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: are you using a plugin for this ?

Comment: No, I'm not using a plugin.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style refer to this to style the tooltip as per your convenience.

Comment: Thanks, I've added some styling to my code but i still can't get it to work, i seem to of broken it now.

Comment: You're missing a comma between your position and content property. position: { my: "left+15 center", at: "right center"},

Comment: ahhh, driving myself insane over here... it was the comma. Thanks Shane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using jQuery UI for this, there is a position option available. You can pass it like you have passed the event handlers. Just add the following to the options parameter to the `tooltip()` function. You can find the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j77eB/4/).

```
position:{ my: "left+15 center", at: "right center" }
```

jQuery UI tooltip documentation for position is [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position).

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there a good place to insert it into the code. I broke it on my first go..

Comment: I updated my code but i'm still having a problem, it's broke. I'm not sure if i really understand the setter position. So, i'm assuming there is another step.

Comment: can you please help me configure. Thank you.

Comment: Ananthan Unni is correct. Your code is broke because you forgot to put a comma between your position and content properties :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `qTip2` plugin for this.

Demo: http://qtip2.com/demos